# An unknown differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have problems with differential equation.

$(xy)dx+(x-y)dy=0$

I tried to solve this by :

1- homogenous method

2- substitution  $z=\frac{x}{y}$

3- Find an Integrator factor

But unfortunately i could not...

Can anyone help me to solve this !?

Thanks.

Comment: @Moo So what's your solution?

Comment: Maybe the equation is $(x+y)dx+(x-y)dy=0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$xy~dx+(x-y)~dy=0$

$x\dfrac{dx}{dy}=1-\dfrac{x}{y}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $t=-\ln y$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{dx}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{dy}=-\dfrac{1}{y}\dfrac{dx}{dt}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{x}{y}\dfrac{dx}{dt}=1-\dfrac{x}{y}$

$x\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x-y$

$x\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x-e^{-t}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf or in http://www.iaeng.org/IJAM/issues_v43/issue_3/IJAM_43_3_01.pdf